# translation in JS?

Tags: translation, javascript

Basically need to generate custom(some different then yes no) messeges(alert) in JS , how to deal with translation in it?

Comment: do you mean translation from, say, English to Spanish?

Comment: Well lets say we have some warning to show like "do you really want to delete this item" and what is gonna be DRY and efficient way to deal with it in multilingual site?

Comment: Are you already using an existing javascript library? Many of them already have some way of doing localization.

Comment: Some newer answers would be http://airbnb.io/polyglot.js/ and https://www.i18next.com/

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Plese take a look at [jQuery-i18n](http://recurser.com/articles/2008/02/21/jquery-i18n-translation-plugin/) translation plugin

```
var my_dictionary = { 
    "some text"  : "a translation",
    "some more text"  : "another translation"
}
$.i18n.load(my_dictionary);


$('div#example').text($.i18n._('some text'));
```

And [jQuery localisation](http://keith-wood.name/localisation.html)

```
$.localise('js/greeting');
$('#greeting').val(greeting);
$('#languages').val($.localise.defaultLanguage);
$('#changeLocale').change(function() {
    var newLang = $(this).val();
    $.localise('js/greeting', {language: newLang, loadBase: true});
    $('#greeting').val(greeting);
    $('#languages').val(newLang);
});
```

Or, If you really want more translation than looking up data, try [google translate api](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxlanguage/documentation/#Examples)

```
google.language.translate("Hello world", "en", "es", function(result) {
  if (!result.error) {
    var container = document.getElementById("translation");
    container.innerHTML = result.translation;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this JQuery plugin
http://www.openxrest.com/translatejs

1 - Include the "trn" class to the text you want to translate:

```
<span class="trn">text to translate</span>
```

2 - Define a dictionary:

```
var dict = {
  "text to translate": {
    pt: "texto para traduzir"
  },
  "Download plugin": {
    pt: "Descarregar plugin",
    en: "Download plugin"
  }
}
```

3 - Translate the entire page body:

```
var translator = $('body').translate({lang: "en", t: dict}); //use English
```

4 - Change to another language:

```
translator.lang("pt"); //change to Portuguese
```