# Translating text while type in textarea in php

Tags: php, translation

I want to translate my text to other language like french or Spanish while i am typing my English content. So that user do not need to re-type in other language for same content. is there any way to do this in php.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do that with php.

You must use JavaScript and the [google translate api](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/?csw=1#Examples)

Check this: [translation in JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2377244/translation-in-js)